# How to update a collection inside a document in FIrestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here are some current pictures of my Firestore:

[image: firestore]
^ Tapped on parent habit, the *1* is only supposed to be under subHabits but it gets duplicated

[image: firestore2]
^ here is where I would like elapsedDuration to be updated for the sub habit 1

[image: firestore3]
^ but it only updates for *1* and is created only when I press pause

I believe `toggleSubHabitStatus` is causing this but I don't know to make it so it updates in the parent habits subHabits collection and not be re-created in top level 'habits' .. any help is appreciated! I'm new

```
class SubFocusScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final SubHabit subHabit;

  const SubFocusScreen({required this.subHabit});

  @override
  _SubFocusScreenState createState() => _SubFocusScreenState();
}

class _SubFocusScreenState extends State<SubFocusScreen> {
  late Timer? _timer;
  bool _isTimerRunning = false;
  Duration _elapsedTime = Duration.zero;

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  late int _elapsedSeconds;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _elapsedTime = widget.subHabit.elapsedDuration;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _toggleStarted(SubHabit subHabit) {
    setState(() {
      subHabit.isStarted = !subHabit.isStarted;
    });
  }

  void toggleSubHabitStatus(SubHabit subHabit) {
    _toggleStarted(subHabit);


    final parentHabitId = subHabit.parentHabitId; 
    final subHabitId = subHabit.id; 

    final subHabitRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('habits')
        .doc(parentHabitId) 
        .collection('subHabits')
        .doc(subHabitId); 

    subHabitRef
        .update({'elapsedDuration': _elapsedTime.inSeconds})
        .then((_) {
      print('SubHabit updated successfully');
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Failed to update subHabit: $error');
    });
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    setState(() {
      _isTimerRunning = true;
      _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
        setState(() {
          _elapsedTime += const Duration(seconds: 1);
        });
      });

      _toggleStarted(widget.subHabit);

      final parentHabitId = widget.subHabit.parentHabitId; // Retrieve the parent habit ID
      final subHabitId = widget.subHabit.id; // Retrieve the sub habit ID

      final subHabitRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('habits')
          .doc(parentHabitId) // Use parent habit ID as the document ID
          .collection('subHabits')
          .doc(subHabitId); // Use sub habit ID as the document ID

      subHabitRef
          .set(widget.subHabit.toMap())
          .catchError((error) {
        print('Error updating subHabit: $error');
      });
    });
  }

  void _pauseTimer(SubHabit subHabit, Duration elapsedDuration) {
    setState(() {
      if (_isTimerRunning) {
        _timer?.cancel();
        _timer = null;
        _elapsedSeconds = elapsedDuration.inSeconds;
        _isTimerRunning = false;

        _toggleStarted(subHabit);

        final parentHabitId = subHabit.parentHabitId; // Retrieve the parent habit ID
        final subHabitId = subHabit.id; // Retrieve the sub habit ID

        final subHabitRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('habits')
            .doc(parentHabitId) // Use parent habit ID as the document ID
            .collection('subHabits')
            .doc(subHabitId); // Use sub habit ID as the document ID

        subHabitRef
            .update({'elapsedDuration': _elapsedSeconds})
            .catchError((error) {
          print('Error updating subHabit: $error');
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Focus'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.chevron_left,
            size: 40,
            color: _isTimerRunning ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_isTimerRunning) {
              _pauseTimer(widget.subHabit, _elapsedTime);
            } else {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Column(
            children: [
              CustomCircularProgressIndicator(
                value: _elapsedTime.inSeconds.toDouble() / 3600,
                valueColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                strokeWidth: 16.0,
                habitName: widget.subHabit.name,
                elapsedTime: Text(
                  '${_elapsedTime.inMinutes}:${(_elapsedTime.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 80),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  if (_isTimerRunning) {
                    _pauseTimer(widget.subHabit, _elapsedTime);
                  } else {
                    _startTimer();
                  }
                  toggleSubHabitStatus(widget.subHabit); // Call the method to update the sub habit fields
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 80.0,
                  height: 80.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    _isTimerRunning ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                    size: 40.0,
                    color:
                        _isTimerRunning ? Colors.yellow : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `parentHabitId` and/or `subHabitId` don't have a value, which means you have a parameterless call to `doc`, which then leads to `doc()` generating a new document ID.

To verify that the variables don't have a value, `print()` them in your code right before you use them. Better yet, put an block to guard against this condition:

```
if (parentHabitId != null && subHabitId != null) {
  ... your code that writes to the database
}
else {
  throw 'parentHabitId or subHabitId is not initialized';
}
```